# Working with Soap, xml and XSLT

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, soap

I have been using XSLT to transform xml to html and its been okay until now that i have to convert a Soap Xml response to the same output and I cant seem to find a way to call the nodes and use them. [XML version here](http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYix/3) .The Problem is when I try changing the more or less similar soap response using XSLT and would like a way to get this done to be like the above mentioned xml example

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <ProcessRequestTrans43Response xmlns="https://secure.transunion.co.za/TUBureau">
      <ProcessRequestTrans43Result>
        <RawData />
        <ResponseStatus>Success</ResponseStatus>
        <ProcessingStartDate>2015-12-21T10:37:09.6260543+02:00</ProcessingStartDate>
        <ProcessingTimeSecs>1.6709999999999998</ProcessingTimeSecs>
        <UniqueRefGuid>f3e76769-5b1f-44ae-82ff-3c7f96f4fd7a</UniqueRefGuid>
        <AddressNA08>
          <AddressNA08>
            <ConsumerNo>645390100</ConsumerNo>
            <InformationDate>20151118</InformationDate>
            <Line1>52 CORLETT DR</Line1>
            <Line2>WANDERERS OFFICE PARK</Line2>
            <Suburb>ILLOVO</Suburb>
            <City>JOHANNESBURG</City>
            <PostalCode>2196</PostalCode>
            <ProvinceCode>GP</ProvinceCode>
            <Province>GAUTENG</Province>
            <AddressPeriod>00</AddressPeriod>
            <OwnerTenant />
            <AddressChanged>N</AddressChanged>
          </AddressNA08>
          <AddressNA08>
            <ConsumerNo>645390100</ConsumerNo>
            <InformationDate>20120109</InformationDate>
            <Line1>MABETSHE ADMIN AREA</Line1>
            <Line2>MTHATHA</Line2>
            <Suburb />
            <City>UMTATA</City>
            <PostalCode>5100</PostalCode>
            <ProvinceCode>EC</ProvinceCode>
            <Province>EASTERN CAPE</Province>
            <AddressPeriod>03</AddressPeriod>
            <OwnerTenant />
            <AddressChanged>N</AddressChanged>
          </AddressNA08>
        </AddressNA08>
        <AKANamesNK04>
          <AKANamesNK04>
            <RecordSeq>01</RecordSeq>
            <Part>001</Part>
            <PartSeq>01</PartSeq>
            <ConsumerNo>645390100</ConsumerNo>
            <InformationDate>20101215</InformationDate>
            <AKAName>NONDLOBO,ZANILE</AKAName>
          </AKANamesNK04>
          <AKANamesNK04>
            <RecordSeq>02</RecordSeq>
            <Part>001</Part>
            <PartSeq>01</PartSeq>
            <ConsumerNo>645390100</ConsumerNo>
            <InformationDate>19980428</InformationDate>
            <AKAName>NONDLOBO,ZANELA</AKAName>
          </AKANamesNK04>
        </AKANamesNK04>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am new to this soap methods and namespaces.

Comment: Did you add soap envelope related namespaces to your xslt while trying it ? in case you traversing from `/soap:Envelope` in case you change directly to tag like `//tagname` it might work, you can try using either options

Comment: @Rahul that didnt work, it still came out blank

Comment: Are you using the same xslt as in the link given?Is the soap payload give above valid? i found unclosed tags

Comment: After correcting soap payload i got an html body

Comment: @Rahul Yes i am using the same XSLT as in the given link

Comment: @Rahul could you please give me a link to the corrected payload please

Comment: check [here](http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYix/4)

Comment: @Rahul Could u please show me what u changed so that it started working

Comment: @Rahul could you please take a look at the following [link](http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYix/5) as I cant seem to be able to call the nodes individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the link that @Rahul posted [a link](http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYix/4)